# Play Console: Flutter App You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added app bundles

Tags: flutter, google-play-console

[image]

I am using Flutter to release the Android app. I have some updates and I am trying to release the one. However, there is an error saying that `You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added app bundles`. I am quite lost what I have to do in this case. Play Console doesn't explicitly say anything about it.

What have I done wrong, and how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version code for the app bundle that you're uploading is probably lower (or lesser) than the current app bundle on your play store. Check the version code of the app bundle on play store and increase it. Than try again to rollout with higher version code

Comment: where does one find the version code of the app bundle?